# String to XML - Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to add the attribute `trust` to one XML. My problem is that currently I have the `value` as a `string`, so I can not use the following code:

```
trusted (escaped) {
  escape.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    }
  }]);
}
```

Is it possible to convert a `string` into a `XML`? I would like to convert `escaped`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to convert a string into an XML. You need to use the `DOMParser` Class. Try something like this to convert:

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
let xml = parser.parseFromString( escaped, "text/xml");
```